# facing issues with spring-Data-jpa 2.5.5 to 2.5.6 BeanCreationFiled due to NullPointerException

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA repository after upgrading from version 2.5.5 to version 2.5.6, and you suspect it's related to the interfaces.
When upgrading between patch versions (e.g., from 2.5.5 to 2.5.6), it's unusual for Spring Data JPA to introduce breaking changes that would cause your repository interfaces to stop working. However, there might be subtle changes or bugs that affect how Spring Data JPA interacts with your repositories.

I'm suspecting it relative to Interfaces Query Creation issue